# Finding the fields between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I would like to find the fields between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. I know the degree of $\mathbb{Q}=(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})/\mathbb{Q}$ is $8$ and its Galois group is isomorphic to $D_4$ (sometimes called $D_8$). Hence, there are exactly $8$ fields between $\mathbb{Q}=(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. I've been able to find $6$ of them: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})$. Which ones am I missing? I believe the fields should be between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})$ but I can't find them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}})$ ?
Because $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}}+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}$...

Comment: Very interesting. How were you able to make this observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgroups of the dihedral group... four reflections, each of which generates a subgroup of order $2$/index $4$. The rotation group, of order $4$/index $2$. The $180^\circ$ rotation, of order $2$/index $4$. Since that last one is the center, it combines with the reflections to make two more groups of order $4$/index $2$; each has two of the reflections and the two central elements.

The three order $4$ groups each correspond to fields of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, generated by a single square root. You've found those three. The five groups of order $2$ correspond to fields of degree $4$, each generated by something with two square roots in it. You've got three of those, but there should be two more.

Now, another way to look at this - it's the splitting field of a fourth degree polynomial with those two roots and their negatives. Explicitly, that polynomial is $$\left(x^2-(3+\sqrt{7})\right)\left(x^2-(3-\sqrt{7})\right)=x^4-6x^2+2$$
How do the order-2 elements in the group act on the roots? A permutation of order $2$ is some combination of $1$-cycles and $2$-cycles; either we have two pairs of roots that swap with each other, or one pair that swaps and two elements that stay fixed. In the dihedral group, the $180^\circ$ rotation and two of the reflections are two-pair swaps, while the other two reflections each swap one of the pairs from the rotation.

So, which ones have you found? Fixing one of those roots $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}$ or $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}$ will also fix its negative. Those are the two corner reflections, which each swap a pair of elements and fix the other two. The $180^\circ$ reflection, in the center of the group, comes from intersecting any two order-$4$ subgroups - or from combining their fields. That's $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{9+2\sqrt{14}})$ (An arbitrary choice for generator there).

That leaves two subgroups, the side reflections. Those will swap across pairs. The first interchanges $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}$ with $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}}$ - so it'll fix their sum
$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}+\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}} = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}+3-\sqrt{7}+2\sqrt{3^2-7}}=\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}}$$
The second interchanges $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}$ with $-\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}}$, so it'll fix their sum
$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}-\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}} = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}+3-\sqrt{7}-2\sqrt{3^2-7}}=\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{2}}$$
The final two fields are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{2}})$, corresponding to the edge reflections in the group.

Incidentally, we can see that those two fields each have $\sqrt{2}$ in them, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ corresponds to the order-$4$ subgroup of the center and the two edge reflections. The group of the center and the two corner reflections corresponds to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, and the rotation subgroup to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})$. There - not just all the fields, but a way to match them to the groups, aside from the arbitrary choice of which reflections take the plus signs inside those square roots.

> I believe the fields should be between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{7}})$

Indeed they are.

Comment: I see. So it seems a common approach is to choose fields generated by the sum of the non-fixed roots of some polynomial by the subgroups of the Galois group, right?

Comment: Really, its that we have some subset that's sent to itself as an orbit, and the symmetric polynomials of them are fixed. Here, with two elements, that's the sum and the product. The product is just $\sqrt{2}$, so that's not going to generate the whole field, and we look to the sum.

Comment: So it appears in the end that you wanted to determine all the subfields of your biquadratic field $L$. Why didn't you say so right from the start, instead of asking 3 successive questions, first on the subextensions of $L/Q(\sqrt {3+\sqrt 7})$, then of $L/Q(\sqrt 14)$ ? Besides, the final solution comes from the answers to these questions + the hint of @Mindlack yesterday. Your lack of reaction to the first 2 answers  could be, in the worst case, interpreted as a lack of courtesy.

Comment: I didn't even notice the other two questions until now - but yeah, that's not the way to do things. If you've got a question, ask the whole thing immediately. It's OK to ask a question, get a response that provokes an extension of the question, and then ask the extended question, but it doesn't look like that's what happened here.